# Chrome Crash in Citrix workaround

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, citrix

It is not recommended to use Chrome in Citrix.
However some companys have a "desired" and needed use for chrome.

However chrome is likely to crash more or less often in citrix and then you cant get it up again without deleting the "local chrome" folder which requires often some type of helpdesk.

Answer (score -1):

Therefore I made a little script I wanted to share maybe its outside already maybe some have use for it.

```
$myID = (Get-Process -PID $pid).SessionId
try{
    If (Get-Process | where ProcessName -Like "chrome" |where SI -like $myID)
    {
        Write-Host "Stopping Chrome"
        Get-Process | where ProcessName -Like "chrome" |where SI -like $myID | Stop-Process
        Write-Host "Chrome stopped"
    }else{
    }
}catch{
    Write-Host "Cant stop Chrome"
}
try{
    Write-Host "Start Repair"
    #Path where AppData Local gets stored  
    #$env:computername should respond the actual terminal server
    $path = "\\$env:computername\c$\users\$env:username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome"
    Remove-Item -Path $path -Recurse -Force
    Write-Host "Repaird"
}catch{
    Write-Host "Repair didnt work"
}
```